# With .htaccess, allow a specific set of Wordpress pages to be served over HTTPS://, and redirect all others back to HTTP://

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I only want a specific set of pages on my Wordpress website to be served over https. All other pages should redirect back to http://.

Using the below .htaccess rewrite rules I can successfully redirect unwanted https:// requests back to http://, but when I try to access one of my allowed https:// pages it redirects back to my blog's homepage for some reason.

https:// mywebsite.com/blog/random-page >>>> http:// mywebsite.com/blog/random-page/ (Good)

https:// mywebsite.com/blog/ssl-page >>>> http:// mywebsite.com/blog/ (Bad, this URL shouldn't be redirecting at all.)

I'm not sure what's going on, I think there is a conflict between my RewriteCond's? 
Any help would be appreciated! Thank you

**My .htaccess file**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/ssl-page/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/another-ssl-page/$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Why? It'll be a lot simpler (and more secure as your session won't be served over both HTTP and HTTPS) to serve the whole blog over SSL.

Answer (score 0):

For that specific example, the problem is here:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/ssl-page/ [NC]
```

You state that `/blog/ssl-page` redirects to HTTP. It's because your first RewriteCond isn't matched - it expects a trailing slash.

You can try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/ssl-page/?$ [NC]
```

to make the trailing slash optional.